# Angular module accessing main app data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have multiple apps developed in Ionic 2 and 3. They share the same login server, and as the login code was the same in all apps, I splitted out into a independent git repository. In the app/ folder of each app there are a config.ts file with:

```
export const APPNAME = 'appname';
export const API = 'https://api.appname.com';
```

I include login module as an angular module in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainApp
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    LoginModule.forRoot()
]
```

And the login.module.ts is:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    providers: [AuthService]
})
export class LoginModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LoginModule,
            providers: [AuthService]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that module needs APPNAME and API address to do login stuff. The entire module is independent of main app, and I added to the project as a git submodule located in src/providers/login. But when in page component of module like LoginPage or RegisterPage i need these constants, I do:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { APPNAME, API } from '../../app/config';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-login',
   templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
```

It is the only line of code that that specifically references main app. I want to inverse that reference by passing config via forRoot() in main app, but I do not know how to retrieve it inside page component of module. Should I to import them somehow into the AuthService, and accesing then via service in page components? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved passing data through service. In app.module.ts add app data:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainApp
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    LoginModule.forRoot({APPNAME, API})
]
```

And in module, pass it into service:

```
export class LoginModule {
    static forRoot(appData: any): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LoginModule,
            providers: [AuthService, { provide: 'appData', useValue: appData }]
        }
    }
}
```

In the service, Inject it:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    @Inject('appData') public config
  ) {
    console.log(config)
  }
[...]
```

**EDIT: This solution do not work in AOT mode, you need to export as a factory function and create one instance in service**

```
export function AppConfig() {
    return {
        APPNAME: APPNAME,
        API: API
    };
}

constructor(
  @Inject('appData') _appData: any
) {
  this.config = _appData();
```